# How to read files with messy unreadable name?

Tags: python, pandas, file-io, path, directory

I have a lot of data files with unreadable name:

[image]

Within python, i can use glob.glob to find them.
But when i tried to use pandas to read the file, error occurs.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
cwd=os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
for file in glob.glob("S*.xls"):
    temp=pd.read_excel(file)
```

Here is the error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'Shibor\xa8\xbay?Y2006.xls'
```

May i ask, how can i find the files with name like "ShiborÊý¾Ý2015.xls" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unicode file names/path add a "u" prefix, like this:

```
for file in glob.glob(u"S*.xls"):
    temp=pd.read_excel(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a unicode character in the filename.  You need to send a properly encoded string to to pandas to open the file.  See [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9438) open issue for pandas.  Honestly, I would just fix the file names in your windows/ gui environment and try and get the process that is generating the files to give you a better name.

In the future, it would be helpful if you stated the version of python and your flavor of operating system.